# AccessControlException loading drools class in webstart application

Tags: java, java-web-start, drools

I have a webstart application that loads/evaluates drools rules. When I run the application as a standalone client, the code works fine. But when run as webstart application (Java 1.7u21), I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getParent(Unknown Source)
at org.drools.rule.JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader.loadClass(JavaDialectRuntimeData.java:581)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

This may be related to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3540.

I have signed all the jars and in my JNLP I have all-permissions.

```
<security> 
<all-permissions/> 
</security>
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Answer (score 0):

Provide the value for **codebase** as * in your jnlp file then try again.

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="*" href="">
```

It works for me.